# Anyone know of any late night co-working spaces in London?

Tags: london, internet

I'll be working remotely in London for the next few days, but will be on Eastern US time hours. Anyone know of any co-working spaces / internet cafes that are open late night (until 10/11 pm local time)?

I'm currently staying in Shepherd's Bush, but I'm willing to take the tube to get to a good spot. Things I'm looking for, in order of importance -

- Solid WiFi (most important)
- Open Late
- Quiet enough to get work done (I was at Shoreditch Grind today, and the music was approaching clubbing levels)
- independent cafes / co-working spaces are preferred
- proximity (least important)

Comment: Starbucks or Costa Coffee. Or just about anywhere else.

Comment: For the cost of a sim card plus something like £2 you can have unlimited 3G data on your phone for a week, too, allowing you to tether literally anywhere (as long as you have battery or an AC outlet).

Comment: Why the close votes? Seems like a very reasonable question

Comment: I didn't cast a close vote, but your question seems to assume that everything is very local.  The Docklands is quite a ways away from Marylebone, which is quite a ways from Knightsbridge, which is quite a ways from Kilburn, which is quite a ways from Chelsea, etc etc.  What's the use of a great internet cafe in Earl's Court if you're staying in Bow?  Way too broad.

Comment: @GayotFow I'm currently staying in Shepherd's Bush, but today I visited a cafe in Shoreditch because I found a cafe that was open late & had solid Wi-fi (check out 'Look Mum No Hands'). The tube works well, and I think it's a fair assumption that people would use it to get to a spot where they can work for several hours.

Comment: Also, I've found this to be fairly useful - http://blog.locappy.com/blog/best-cafes-and-places-to-work-from-in-london

Comment: I've updated my question to be more clear as to what's important to me.